# Unable to display variable content inside a input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I'm using jquery, JS and html with a parse.com backend.I cannot find an exact solution on SO or google to this issue.

I've saved a string variable from a db using

```
document.getElementById("div_name").innerHTML = name;
```

I'm able to display it on the html page using

```
<div id= "div_name"></div>
```

Now I want to add it to an input box and have the string display as the default value in the box. I thought I could do this using

```
<input type="text" id="div_name"/>
```

But this only displays a blank box, no data. What have I missed in my approach please?

Comment: also you have duplicate id,and use value instead of innerHtml

Comment: No duplicate id, reread the question

Comment: @nicael what makes you so  sure that there is no duplicate id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tilwin Joy pointed out, with pieces from original post, e.g.,

```
<div id= "div_name"></div>
<input type="text" id="div_name"/>
```

there may be *2* `element`s with same `id` ?

try

html

```
<div id= "div_name"></div>
<input type="text" class="div_name" value="" />
```

js (utilizing jquery library)

```
$(".div_name")
.val($("#div_name").text())
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6L7jK/

Comment: No duplicate id, REREAD the question

Comment: This appears to return a blank text box, I've created a quick fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ELUKt/

Comment: @Dano007 what is supposed to happen in that fiddle? it's full of errors. check the console..

Comment: @Dano007 See http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6L7jK/ Note Not certain about remainder of pieces.

Comment: @TilwinJoy Not certain about remainder of pieces ? Removed from jsfiddle at comment above, will edit post to include. jsfiddle only addresses requirement of original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<input>`, should be

```
document.getElementById("div_name").value = name;
```

Comment: That's right - innerHTML is for setting the text between the start and end tags (like `<div>` and `</div>`), but an input field doesn't display text between `<input>` and `</input>`.  Instead it uses the `value` attribute.

Comment: To help I've created a quick jfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ELUKt/ I'm sorry but I dont 100% follow your answer. Can you help visualise it? thanks